# How did executable stacks work in x86 protected mode?

Tags: x86, kernel, osdev, memory-segmentation, protected-mode

Section 4.7.2 of the  the AMD64 Developer Manual Volume 2 (System Programming) which describes Code-Segment Descriptors in legacy modes states:

> Code segments establish the processor operating mode and execution privilege- level. The segments generally contain only instructions and are execute-only, or execute and read- only. **Software cannot write into a segment whose selector references a code-segment descriptor.**

If code segments are the only executable segments, and they cannot be written to, how did executable stacks on 32 bit systems work?

Comment: I untagged x86-64 because long mode enforces a flat memory model, where `ss:off` is the same location as `cs:off`, so anything you write to the stack can be jumped to, depending on page permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code segments are executable (but not writable). Stack segments must be read/write (and aren't executable).

Each segment has a base address and a limit. Software provides offset/s into segment/s (e.g. the instruction pointer is an offset into the area described by  the `cs` segment, the stack pointer is an offset into the area described by the `ss` segment); where the CPU checks that the offset is within the segment's limit, then adds the base address of the segment to the offset to determine the (linear) address.

**If the code segment and stack segment refer to the same memory (e.g. have the same base address and limit); then that same memory can be executed (using the code segment) and read/write (using the stack segment).**

Note that most operating systems don't/didn't use segmentation (they set all segment base addresses to zero and all segment limits to "max" so that it behaves like there's no segments); and "all segment refer to the same memory" is very common. For protection, most operating systems use paging only.

Comment: Oh interesting, `mov [cs: esp], eax` segfaults (in compat mode under x86-64 Linux where `mov [ss: esp], eax` runs fine), I guess because the CS segment override applies the read-only segment permissions of the code segment.  I hadn't thought about segment overrides implying permissions as well as a base.  But that does stop a program with a non-flat memory model from modifying its own code unless it can address that linear address via another segment.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes - most people don't really notice things like that (when all segments refer to the same memory there's little reason to use segment override prefixes, and with "default/implied segments" everything is mostly well behaved). For more fun (without segment overrides), consider `mov ebp,0xFFFFFFFF` then `mov [ebp],eax` running on a "flat memory" OS that's trying to pretend that there's no segmentation - for "segmentation literally disabled" you'd expect wrapping, for "all segments are the same" you'd expect a general protection fault, and what you actually get is a stack fault.